# Can public IP range be used as private IP?

Tags: networking, ip

As per IANA standards, below is the range for private IP,

```
10.0.0.0 to 10.255.255.255
172.16.0.0 to 172.31.255.255
192.168.0.0 to 192.168.255.255
```

---

Can IP addresse outside the range(above) used as private IP to communicate packets within a specific network?

Comment: You can use any addressing you like on your own network, but you would never be able to contact any hosts/servers on the the public Internet with public addresses in the same network. For example, you could use the `8.8.8.0/24` network, but you would be unable to use the Google `8.8.8.8` DNS server because your hosts would assume that the address is on the same network.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Basically, you can use ever IP-Address-Range you want in your private network. There is no reglementation against this.

But you have to take precautions to avoid routing-trouble when a machine with an IP-Address that actually belongs to a public range wants to access the internet. Here you have to have a Router or Firewall that is able to NAT your internal address bidirectionally.

Comment: We have a machine with private IP( ouside IANA range) that snmp polls public IP's on internet...How is this possible?

Comment: How can a machine with private IP address(outside IANA) talk to public ip on internet?

Comment: You need a router in between that performs NAT. The easiest way is to use a broadband land line with a public IP-Address. Behind this line you put the router and to your router‘s LAN you connect the private network. That‘s it.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, there is nothing preventing you from setting your static IP to anything you want. It's up to the router to decide where packets are routed. On your internal network, since you own the router, you can decide to use an IP range normally used for public traffic if you are OK with those public servers being inaccessible to you.

Note that this may cause unusual side effects with DNS if your server is running on an IP address to which another domain name resolves. The server would appear to be running on that domain. Maybe this is what you want, although with SSL you would get a warning that the server fingerprint does not match.